# the lua math.random equivalent for c ++?

Tags: c++, lua

is there a similar function in c ++ where I can bind variables to random numbers?

`local xoffset, yoffset, zoffset = math.random(-1, 10), math.random(1, -10), math.random(1, 10)`

Comment: [`std::experimental::randint`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/randint) might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a full suite of random number generation algoriths in [`<random>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random). You can do something like this:

```
    std::default_random_engine e1(r());
    int xoffset = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{-1, 10}(e1);
    int yoffset = std::uniform_int_distribution<int>{-10, 1}(e1);
    ...
```